# When do two massed exert the same centripetal on a point?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

I was reading the mark scheme for 2020 Cambridge A-level physics when I came across a question that reads

The stars S1 and S2 rotate with the same angular velocity ωabout a point P, as illustrated in Fig. 1.2.
Point P is at a distance xfrom the centre of star S 1.
The period of rotation of the stars is 44.2 years.

And then it asked:

By considering the forces acting on the two stars, show that the ratio of the masses of the stars is given by

mass of S1 / mass of S2 = (d– x) / x.

Could anyone explain WHY the gravitational forces on the two masses S1 and S2 are equal, OR in other words, the centripetal forces about point P are the same?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Newton's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion), the magnitude of the gravitational forces on each mass must be the same.

"Centripetal" is just a direction indicator, just like how "horizontal" and "vertical" also indicate directions. Since gravity acts in a line between the bodies, and because the center of rotation lies on this line, the gravitational force is always centripetal. Therefore, since the forces are equal in magnitude, it must be that the centripetal forces acting on each mass are also equal.

Comment: I know that Newton's stated that the gravitational forces on each mass are always the same. However, the thing is that these forces are exerted by one of the two masses on the other, whereas since these masses rotate about the point O (this is where I got confused), the centripetal forces you are talking about are in fact something diffrent from the gravitational forces mentioned above? So, how can you reach the conclusion that these centripetal forces are also equal to each other?

Comment: @ElNiño You seem to be under the misconception that the "centripetal force" is some additional force. It is not. Gravity is a centripetal force in this scenario, just like how it is a vertical force in projectile motion problems. Centripetal is a direction, not a type of force. If you understand why the gravitational forces are equal, then you understand why the centripetal forces are equal, because in this scenario they are the same exact thing.

Comment: But if these 2 masses rotate about the point P (even if the angular velocities are the same), there must be times when the center of rotation does NOT lie on the line connecting these two masses, right? In that case, how come the gravitational forces are exactly centripetal.

Comment: @ElNiño No, the problem says they are orbiting about point $P$, so it will always lie on the line connecting them.